# Insert value from user local storage into load function

Tags: jquery, html, edit

Hi i got a Problem i want to load the value from the user local storage into a function and in that function check if localstorage is provided if its aviable load local user storage if not load a page this is my script so far working insted of first part.

```
        function LoadSample(num){
//Here is the Problem i need sone help please ;)
        $("#code"+num).load('sites/demo'+num+'.html');   if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
        document.getElementById("code1").html = localStorage.userEdits;
       $("#livebtn"+num).css("display", "none");
       $("#codebtn"+num).css("display", "block");
       $("#savebtn"+num).css("display", "none");
       $("#update").css("display", "none");


}

function LoadCode(num){
   $.get('sites/demo'+num+'.html', function(data) {
       $("#code"+num).text(""+data+"");
       if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
       document.getElementById("code1").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;

   });
   $("#codebtn"+num).css("display", "none");
   $("#livebtn"+num).css("display", "block");
   $("#savebtn"+num).css("display", "none");
   $("#update").css("display", "none");
}



</script>
<script>
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Änderungen gespeichert!";

}

function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect if local storage is available (from the latest [Modernizr test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/storage/localstorage.js)):

```
...
var mod = 'modernizr';
try {
    localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
    localStorage.removeItem(mod);
    return true;
} catch(e) {
    return false;
}
...
```

Comment: dont neeb want to check it if its there allright if not also is there not a simpler way?

Comment: im not very familar with jquery please make it easyier explain a bit more ;)

Comment: I am not trying to offend but it is a bit unclear what you are asking. You wanted to "... check if localstorage is provided if its aviable" and now you "dont neeb want to check it if its there allright".

Comment: that he reads the user content before the php demo page and displays it the second line of script doesnt work

Comment: the second and third and forth line